# Power BI Rest API Dynamic URL Calling Based On Menu

Tags: powerbi

I'm still fairly new to Power BI so trying to understand some theory and approach elements.
The Power BI view would load an initial list from an API (say a list of projects) which the user can then select.

In the back ground this selection would then send a new URL and display data received from either the same or different API URL used in the first instance.

I've done this in the past with Excel but not sure if its possible using Power BI.
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

The use case for context is to be able to select data from an API which has too many records for Power BI direct. By been able to filter before the request and dynamically change the API call the number of records can be vastly reduced while keeping flexibility to not have the data in a downloaded table which is then filtered.

Not sure if DirectQuery - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-about - is my answer or not and if it is how I use it with the above.